# When Zeroc ICE Make A Connection For TCP Proxy

Tags: ice

I am involved in an heterogeneous system and we use ICE(Zeroc) for component's communication. Unfortunately the system seems to be efficient critical and we need to do some investigate to estimate whether ICE could satisfy our requirement.

Firstly, I want to know for TCP proxy, when a connection should be established? I've read the ICE manual roughly and seems no such information to answer my question. So I think the best idea for me is to fall into the depth of ICE source code to find the answer but this is embarrassed to me at the researching stage. Because I'm not familiar to the ICE code so I cannot teach my self to find something I want quickly. So I go to the ICE forum and I want to find something such as the ICE architecture diagram or class diagram. But my ICE account has no privilege to ask even a simplest question.

And I also ask for your help for, do you have any ICE document for coding implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quite complete manual, see for connection establishment:
http://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice/Connection+Establishment

Comment: Yes, this should be one of the articles I wanted. And do you have any ideas for reading the ICE source code? Thanks very much.